# gVim: change colorscheme base on os (desktop) theme

Tags: gvim, colorscheme

How can I set two color schemes in vim, one when the desktop theme is light and one when the desktop theme is dark? It is particularly useful when using gVim, plugin suggestions are welcome

Comment: I'm literally curious, why downvote?

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to script it yourself. There are some tutorials on how to do it for Vim running on a terminal, that you would have to adapt to gVim (and maybe your operating system):

- [Automatic dark mode for terminal applications](https://arslan.io/2021/02/15/automatic-dark-mode-for-terminal-applications/)
- [Automatic dark mode switching for vim and the terminal](https://www.halcyon.hr/posts/automatic-dark-mode-switching-for-vim-and-terminal/)
- [The macOS Dark Mode, your Terminal and Vim](https://stefan.sofa-rockers.org/2018/10/23/macos-dark-mode-terminal-vim/)

If you are on macOS, you could consider switching to MacVim, [which added support for this some years ago](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/pull/929)

I use is auto-dark-mode, but it only runs on Neovim and doesn't support Windows

Comment: thanks, I will try to find a way with your guide, if it will work for me, I will comment here on my findings and mark your response as an answer...

Comment: Sounds good! Also, don't hesitate to write your own answer if you come up with your own script/plug-in